# Defining (overloading) a custom C++ operator

Tags: c++

I am learning C++ and I wondered whether it would be possible to have an operator like `->=` or `.=`. That kind of operator would work like the arithmetic ones (`+=` and so on), however it would check whether both pointers to objects are of the same type. Now I am aware that in C++ you are allowed to overload operators, but apparently the ones I'm after don't exist in C++.
I did try something like this:

```
class Node {
      Node* ptr;
      Node* operator->=(Node * obj);
};
```

But not even this class declaration compiles. 
Then I tried to set up a macro like this `#define ~ ->=` where I swap the complement operator (which would have no use for an object) with the desired one with the idea that the IDE would allow me to overload `~` and then the preprocessor would swap all `->=` with `~`. Apparently that didn't work as well, there was an issue with the macro and I ran out of ideas.

From what I've heard C++ is a very rich and flexible language and I'd be glad to know whether implementing the operator I want would be possible.

Comment: Only defined operators can be overloaded, and still, not all of them. In C++ operator overloading is just syntactic sugar. And please forget the preprocessor.

Comment: You cannot have custom operators. You can only overload existing ones.

Comment: *From what I've heard C++ is a very rich and flexible language* -- Other programmers will try to read your code, and if they start seeing weird operator syntax, all that will do is bring more confusion.  If there really was such an operator, then yes, all the other C++ programmers would be aware of it and be prepared.

Comment: There is a trick to make a "named operator", so you could do `a = b <pow> c;`.  But it's less shenanigans just to make a named member function.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately C++ offers only a limited set of operators for overloading, and for them only a certain amount of parameters are allowed. See [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators).

`#define ~ ->=` preprocessor command doesn't work because it replaces in the wrong direction, and more importantly it is an invalid macro name as it contains more than just alphanumeric characters(as  HolyBlackCat pointed out). You could use some other valid name however, though I would highly advise against that.

```
//Raw.cpp
#define MY_OPERATORxx operator^
#define xx ^ 
void A::MY_OPERATORxx(const Node &n); // --> void A::operator^(const Node &n);

A{} xx A{}; // --> A{} ^ A {}
```

Comment: `->=` is not a valid macro name.

Comment: Macro names should only consist of alphanumeric characters and  `_`.

Comment: Your example will not work. Macros only replace identifiers, not parts of identifiers. The identifier `operatorMY_OPERATOR` remains as-is even though `MY_OPERATOR` is a macro.

Comment: @JaMiT Oh I messed up. It just compiled because it thought operatorMY_OPERATOR was a method name :(

Comment: I’ll change it after I finish my chipotle bowl :3

Comment: @JaMiT Took a little longer, but how about now?

Comment: @Kosta  Looks like it should work. Of course, it doesn't give the desired "`X ->= Y`" syntax, but it shows what could be done with macros.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to define new operators in C++, only the operation of the existing ones can be altered by overloading.

The macro is a very terrible idea and will immediately fail because macro names should only consist of alphanumeric characters and `_`.